# only allow scp no shell

Tags: scp, sshd

can I use /etc/ssh/sshd_config to make it so a user can only scp files to the server but open a shell.  I tried with the commands below but just got connection closed.

Match User website
       X11Forwarding no
       AllowTcpForwarding no
       ForceCommand scp

Answer (score 0):

You need to set user's shell to rssh - http://www.pizzashack.org/rssh/ . This shell allows executing sftp/scp requests only.

Comment: This answer should be removed! It's really dated and may confuse people - scponly, rssh and similar tools are all dead and removed from all OS repos many years ago. rssh has unpatched vulnerability known for years